# Cross-site file upload with form validation

Tags: django, file-upload, form-submit, cross-site

I would like to upload a file to remote server from some form in an iframe. But before submitting the form I'd like to check if it's valid using Django's built-in systems. So first how to upload file to a remote server without redirecting. Do I only need to specify empty iframe as form's target? And secondly how to wrap around submition I don't know, maybe some ajaxSubmit event, to evaluate the form and only when it's valid and then perform the submit itself (so probably the function should return True etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly, but it sounds like you want to use Django's server-based form validation on the data entered in the form. The only way to do this is to actually submit the form to the Django server.

Normally, the way to upload a file to a "remote" server is by submitting a form and having that remote server process the form submission (including the file content). If the remote server is also django-based, you can use the same validation (assuming that you're not using [CSRF](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) that is -- I'm not certain whether it's possible to use CSRF to point to another server, mostly since that is part of the whole point of CSRF).

So, what is your real goal? Is there some second server (not the django one) that needs the file? If so, I'd process the upload on the Django server and perform the validation, then use a connection like ftp, sftp, scp, etc. to copy the file over to the other server.

Alternatively, you can write your own JavaScript (or existing JS framework) to validate the form and then submit the form to the remote server.

There's no need to use an iframe (empty or not), by the way. That's only necessary if your goal is to do an asynchronous submit of the file without leaving the page.